# Cloudinary - direct delete , jquery file upload, hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, cloudinary

I did multiple image upload direct from browser using jquery file upload + cloudinary and I need to build direct delete of uploaded image also. I upload image using  this file tag

```
<input name="file" type="file"
 class="cloudinary-fileupload"
 data-cloudinary-field="image_id[]" 
 data-form-data=" ... html-escaped JSON data ... "
 multiple="multiple >
</input>
```

after uploading, it creates hidden field like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="images_id[]"
value="image/upload/v1404930923/image_name">
```

What I want to do is to make additional attribute on this hidden field every time I upload an image, for example "data-id". I need to delete proper hidden field when I delete file from Cloudinary direct from the browser.

[cloudinary documentation - Direct upload file tag](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_image_upload#direct_upload_file_tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the hidden field has a value, like: `resource_type/type/path#signature`, where each is available on the result object of the `cloudinarydone` handler, you can reconstruct this and traverse the hidden fields and find a matching value, and then add the attribute that you want.

Comment: @hodiecode How did you achieve this direct delete from browser, cn you please paste detail here ?

Comment: @sunil First I need to get signature so I send post via ajax to my own controller where I can create signature and return it. Having all needed data I can send ajax to cloudinary servers.
To build my signature I use something like this
`signature = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest "public_id=#{image_id}&timestamp=#{timestamp}#{api_secret}"`

docs:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#deleting_images

http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#request_authentication