# Cloudinary Callback with PHP and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, cloudinary

I've successfully uploaded images to my cloudinary account, but I can't figure out where cloudinary is sending the `image_id`? This is confusing, because the documentation seems to indicate that `cloudinary_cors.html` is the target of Cloudinary's callbacks, but that makes little sense, becuase I can't use php to store `POST`'ed variables if it's a `.html` file.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the `cloudinarydone` event in order to make use of the returned values. It should look something like that:

```
$('.cloudinary-fileupload').bind('cloudinarydone', function(e, data) { 
    ...
    YOUR CODE COMES HERE
    ...
});
```

Comment: Okay great! Yeah i ended up using this to fill a hidden form with the values and then submit it, using jquery. That's the idea, right? Seems pretty manual... I would have thought the Cloudinary PHP framework would have a built-in way to do this?

Comment: This is done automatically in some Frameworks, such as Rails, Django, etc.
Cloudinary's jQuery plugin [generates an hidden field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661949/cloudinary-direct-delete-jquery-file-upload-hidden-fields) after upload is done, which contains the new resource's identifier. This property can be parsed and public-ID / version / extension can a all be extracted from there.